# jQuery Error: Invalid object initializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code in my page:

```
<div id="data_body_container" style="overflow: auto; width: 880px; height: 500px;">
...
</div>
```

and then below in the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function() {
                    var windowWidth = $(window).width() - 50;
                    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 50;

            $('#data_body_container').css({'width': windowWidth+'px', 'height': windowHeight+'px','overflow:auto'});

       alert('Resize to '+ windowWidth + 'x'+windowHeight );
        })

    </script>
```

But my Firefox error console says "invalid object initializer" and points to this line if click the entry. Where is the error? It seems right to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's this bit on the end:

```
'overflow:auto'
```

That should be:

```
overflow: 'auto'
//or, to match your styling...
'overflow': 'auto'
```

Overall it should look like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width() - 50,  
      windowHeight = $(window).height() - 50;

  $('#data_body_container').css({'width': windowWidth+'px', 'height': windowHeight+'px', 'overflow': 'auto'});
  alert('Resize to ' + windowWidth + 'x' + windowHeight);
});
```

Even if it's a constant value, the format still has to be `{ name: 'value' }`, a single string just isn't valid syntax :)